# How to print a pattern 16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16 using recursion in java?

Tags: java, recursion, design-patterns

```
class Rec
{
    public int pattern(int n)
    {
        if(n>=1)
        return pattern(n-5);
        else
        return pattern(n+5);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a=16;
        Rec ob=new Rec();
        System.out.print("16\t"+ob.pattern(a));
    }   
}
```

Above is my code which compiles successfully but doesn't give any output.

Comment: What is the question? What does not work?  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Look at your code and ask yourself where you are actually printing anything.

Comment: "doesn't give any output"? Isn't it throwing a `StackOverflowError` exception?

Comment: Any recursive method needs a "base case" - a way of escaping from the repeated calls to the method.

Comment: @YoungSpice I guess it gives exception ! So, how do I handle it ?

Comment: You handle it by understanding what recursion is, and how it needs a "base case" so that it can terminate instead of recursing infinitely - which is what's happening now. Once you understand the concept, it should be terribly simple to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change The pattern function since it will never break out of recursion. 
Since whatever the value of n be the function calls itself. So without any output the pattern function call goes on.
One thing you can try this:

```
public int pattern(int n)
{
    if(n>=-4){
        System.out.print(""+n+"\t");
        pattern(n-5);
        if(n!=-4)System.out.print(""+n + "\t");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:
    16  11  6   1   -4  1   6   11  16